# What does the following sentence mean in this paragraph?

Tags: british-english, logic

I'm reading [an article of TheEconomist](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/08/11/how-to-prevent-a-war-between-america-and-china-over-taiwan). In the first paragraph(quoted below), I can't understand its last sentence(bolded below). I mean, literally, I think I understand its meaning. But it's not logical I think. There must be somewhere I misunderstand.

> America and China agree on very little these days. Yet on the subject
> of Taiwan, at least in one regard, they are in total harmony. The
> status quo surrounding the self-governing island, which China claims
> and whose thriving democracy America supports, is changing in
> dangerous ways, say officials on both sides. War does not look
> imminent, but the uneasy peace that has held for more than six decades
> is fragile. **Ask them who is at fault, however, and the harmony
> shatters.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says that

1. America and China disagree about many things.
2. They are in total harmony (= they completely agree) about one thing however.
3. That is that the previously stable situation related to Taiwan is changing in dangerous ways.
4. There is no harmony about whose fault that is (America blames China, and vice-versa). If you ask one, it will blame the other.